# MaterialSearchView doesn't get focus on startup - Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I am using MaterialSearchView (https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView), a library to implement SearchView in a Material Design Approach.

It puts a searchview in the toolbar. However don't know how to focus on the search, so that when the actviity starts, the search gets the focus right away and the virtual keyboard appears. It only focuses if i click on the search icon.

```
MaterialSearchView searchView;
        searchView = MaterialSearchView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_view);
searchView.requestFocus();
```

doesn't work.

I tried it from the fragment and from the activity.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean search view will open when the activity start? If you check the library, you will find a function `showSearch()` to open search view.

Comment: when you call request focus on a view, the view's focusable and focusableInTouchMode should be set to true in xml. Try setting focusable and focusableInTouchMode true in xml.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [my implementation of MaterialSearchView](https://github.com/Mauker1/MaterialSearchView), it's possible to open it up without clicking on the Toolbar/Actionbar.

For example, in your `Activity` you could do the following:

```
// Activity:
MaterialSearchView searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
```

Then, anywhere in your code, you could open the view by calling:

```
searchView.openSearch();
```

And close it by calling:

```
searchView.closeSearch();
```

So, you could put the `openSearch()` inside your `onResume()` for example. That way, you'll always have the search view open when your `Activity` starts. You could also call that method from any `Button` on your `Activity`.

**P.S.:** It also have support for search suggestions and search history.

**Bonus:** Have a gif (It's shown in portuguese, but it also supports english, so don't worry).

[image: Material Search View]

For more information on how to set it up, and to see the use cases, you can [check the docs](https://github.com/Mauker1/MaterialSearchView/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: You're welcome! If you liked it and if it helped, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a menu reference object:

```
private Menu menu;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
   this.menu = menu;
//rest of your code here ...
}
```

and then onResume() of your Activity you can programmatically simulate item click like this:

```
onOptionsItemSelected(menu.findItem(R.id.searhView));
```

Comment: I am getting  a null pointer exection on onResume(), that menu is null.